# Using Octopus Deploy with EPiServer to handle database upgrades

Tags: automation, episerver, octopus-deploy

Since EPiServer 7 upgrading to a newer version has involved:

1. Updating all `EPiServer.*` NuGet packages
2. Running `PM > Update-EPiServer` - to upgrade the local database
3. Running `PM > Export-EPiServer` - to produce a set of database upgrade script files that can be run on other servers.

However if only the upgraded EPiServer solution is built and deployed by Octopus Deploy, the database will not be upgraded meaning the site will not run.

Currently I run the `EPiServerPackage` **manually** on a server in each of our environments after a deployment.

I'm trying to decide on the cleanest way to include the `/EPiUpdatePackage` folder and contents running the `Export-EPiServer` command produces so that it will:

- Checked into source control
- Turned into a NuGet package on the build server
- Be deployed by **Octopus Deploy** so that it can be remotely executed on the server the script is deployed to

Comment: May I ask you you don't simply use the updateDatabaseSchema attribute `<episerver.framework updateDatabaseSchema="true">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Eric Herlitz suggestion, I have simply used the `<episerver.framework updateDatabaseSchema="true">` in the `web.config` transforms for the environments I wish to have the database automatically upgraded on.

I'm unsure it this will present a problem if the SQL connection string user does not have the required level of permissions. However in my case, this is working correctly.

Comment: If you need more powerful and customizable tools using Octopus check the SQL templates here https://library.octopus.com/listing